# Rails example applications or plugins/gems for doing photo album in multiple files upload?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-upload, paperclip, photo-gallery, carrierwave

I would like to know is there any Rails example applications or plugins/gems for doing photo albums in multiple file upload? It could have basic functionality like create/edit a album with multiple files upload.